# is there any thing can affect cors at localhost

Tags: cors, nestjs, nestjs-config

I am building Full stack website with ReactJS with vite, NestJS, and typescript
I am facing some issues with cors
I did setup cors at the backend to accept any request from the front end `localhost:5173`

this is main.ts in NestJS

```js
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  app.enableCors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:5173', // specify the allowed origin
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE', // specify the allowed HTTP methods
    credentials: true, // enable credentials (cookies, authorization headers)
  });

  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

I am getting this error

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/auth-client/sign-out. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).`

the function that calls the API

```js
const ClientAuthSignOut = async (userAccessToken: string) => {
  const response = await fetch(`${baseURL}/auth-client/sign-out`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${userAccessToken}`,
    },
  });
  return await response.json();
};
```

this function is called somewhere else

```js
const handleLogout = async () =>
  try {
    const data = await ClientAuthSignOut(token);
    if (data.message === "signed out successfully") {
      dispatch(UNSET_AUTH_DATA());
      localStorage.removeItem("user");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    alert("Something went wrong. Please try again");
  }
};
```

the problem was that it worked fine at first but after that, it started throwing this error and the only way to fix it was by restarting my laptop I am using a Macbook Pro M2 pro

is there anything that may affect cors for localhost

I am calling an api I built with nestJS

Calling api from my backend should return JSON data but I can not call my api because of cors
The only way I can fix it is by restarting my laptop

Comment: Post debugging details like what the preflight headers you're getting back are as well as evidence that you are making the call from `http://localhost:5273`

Comment: I suddenly thought that you might have discovered a `bug`
What you can use is `dev mode`, which has a `hot update` function
The `hot update` caused this `cros` to fail
Maybe you can try stopping this program and running it again
Instead of restarting your own computer

Additionally, if you use `ReactJS`, you can search for `ReactJS proxy`

Comment: I added the function that calls the API with headers

Comment: I did try to stop it and run it again but it did not fix the issue

Comment: I am not using Create react app I am using Vite

Comment: Your main.ts specifies the origin as ```origin: 'http://localhost:5173'``` but the error says you called from http://127.0.0.1:3000. As the url/port dont match but are specified the request fails.

Comment: @A-Tech `https://localhost:5173` is my frontend (reactJS, Vite)
`localhost:3000` or `127.0.0.1:300` is my backend (NestJS)

Comment: @AbdulkaderSafi my bad. no coffee yet :) but you also have 5173 and 5273 as port in your post. Not sure if this is a typo in the question or somewhere in your code. if it runs at 5273 this would also cause this kind of error.

Comment: @A-Tech I am sorry that you not getting your coffee yet, I am fasting myself, it is a typo in the question my frontend running on port 5173 not 5273

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for disturbing but I found the issue somehow 2 servers were working on port 3000 which is strange
I use Obsidian for note taking, project management, and todo lists
and one of the plugins called Slide Preview was running on `localhost:3000`
this plugin allows me to create presentations using markdown and there is a button to run the presentation on the browser I noticed that it was running on port 3000 like my NestJS backend
So I solved the issue by changing the port of the plugin from the settings